# How to use a BASH variable as a variable on a Javascript file function

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, variables

I have test.js file and a test.command file.

test.js:

```
  module.exports.init = function (a) {
      console.log(a);
  };
```

test.command

```
    FOO="$(node -e 'require("/test.js").init("Hello")')"

    echo ${FOO}
```

If I manually type "Hello", the programs works as it should and echo ${FOO} prints "hello".

However, if I do this

```
    BAR="hello"

    FOO="$(node -e 'require("/test.js").init("${BAR}")')"

    echo ${FOO}
```

it prints "${BAR}"

How do I let the shell script know that part is a variable, and should be read as such? If I remove the quotes from the ("${BAR}") part it gives me this error

```
    [eval]:1
    require("/test.js").init(${BAR})
                             ^

    SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash treats `'` and `"` differently

no variable substitution is performed inside `'`

So, do this instead (since javascript treats `'` and `"` identically)

```
BAR="hello"
FOO="$(node -e "require('./test.js').init('${BAR}')")"
echo ${FOO}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to bash scripting so coming from javascript I thought " and ' would be treated the same.